# Can't use RxJava with Hengam SDK

Tags: android, rx-java, hengam

I've recently added [Hengam](https://hengam.io) SDK in my project; but unfortunately I can't use *RxJava* anymore and It causes duplicate exception. It is worth mentioning that prior to adding the SDK to the project everything was working properly.

Here's the stack trace:

```java
Duplicate class io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Completable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.CompletableEmitter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.CompletableObserver found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.CompletableOnSubscribe found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.CompletableSource found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Emitter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Flowable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Maybe found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.MaybeEmitter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.MaybeObserver found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.MaybeOnSubscribe found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.MaybeSource found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Observable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Observable$1 found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableConverter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableOperator found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableSource found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Observer found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Scheduler found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Scheduler$Worker found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.Single found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.SingleEmitter found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.SingleObserver found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.SingleOnSubscribe found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.SingleSource found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.annotations.CheckReturnValue found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.annotations.Nullable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.disposables.Disposables found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.Exceptions found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.ProtocolViolationException found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.Action found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.BiConsumer found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.Consumer found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.Function found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.functions.Predicate found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.observables.GroupedObservable found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
Duplicate class io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject found in modules rxjava-2.0.4.jar (io.hengam.lib:rxjava:2.0.4) and rxjava-2.2.9.jar (io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9)
```

What's wrong with it? Is there any conflict with the SDK or it needs any additional configuration to use *RxJava*?
Any response would be appreciated...

Comment: (not the downvoter) your question title doesn't actually explain to anyone what your problem is :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Is it ok now? :)

Comment: any proof of duplicate entry exception / stack trace?

Comment: @ariefbayu I'll add stack trace to the question soon

Comment: @ariefbayu I've added stack trace to the question

Comment: check out this thread https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/538

Comment: @ariefbayu yeah, I think that's the issue. there is a conflict on *RxJava* version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, [Hengam](http://docs.hengam.io/Android/SDK-Integration/) has a customized RxJava2 (For keeping SDK final size lower). So if you want to use RxJava2 along with Hengam, you need to exclude it's custom RxJava2 and implement the actual library.

```
implementation ('io.hengam.lib:base:1.0.8')  {
   exclude group: 'io.hengam.lib', module: 'rxjava'
}

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9'
```

So the `io.hengam.lib:rxjava` will not be imported to class path and instead, RxJava2 of ReactiveX will be added.

**Note**:
1. Use **RxJava2** version 2.2.9 or higher.
2. The **RxJava3** has a different packaging in compare to RxJava2. So make sure you add **RxJava2**

[Hengam reference in Jcenter](https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/hengam/lib)

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude RxJava group from dependency or remove RxJava dependency from gradle.

```java
implementation ('io.hengam.lib:base:1.0.5')  {
    exclude group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', module: 'rxjava'
}
```

Comment: why `io.reactivex.rxjava2` is set as excluded group?